# gdbでプログラムが動かない

Tags: c++, c, macos, gdb

gdbでデバッグをしようとしてrunをすると

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000f3f: file helloworld.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/RS/Desktop/prog/a.out 
[New Thread 0x1903 of process 28784]
[New Thread 0x1c03 of process 28784]
During startup program terminated with signal ?, Unknown signal
```

となってプログラムが動きません。

また、

```
During startup program terminated with signal SIGTRAP
```

となって終了する場合もあります。
何が問題なのでしょうか。
また、どうすれば解決できるのでしょうか。

OSはmacOS High Sierra 10.13.1です。

Answer (score 3):

Sierra 以降で gdb を使うときによくあるトラブルだそうで、英語版SOにも同様の質問があります。

[GDB kind of doesn't work on macOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702871/gdb-kind-of-doesnt-work-on-macos-sierra/40437725#40437725)

`~/.gdbinit` に `set startup-with-shell off` と書くとか、gdb を新しいものにバージョンアップするなどで解決できるかもしれません。

自分も同様のトラブルに遭遇したことがありますが、gdb の使用を諦めて lldb を使っています。